# Package Dependency

Tags: java, dependency-analysis

I have a huge Java Application with numerous packages. Some of the classes in these packages have dependency on classes in other packages. Given a class, I want to know all the dependent classes on it and vice-versa. A GUI tool should be really helpful.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There's [some useful tools described here](http://sevalapsha.wordpress.com/2008/02/01/java-code-structure-and-dependencies-analysis-tools-for-eclipse/) for the (free) Eclipse IDE. There's also more info on dependency tools with a [comparison against depfinder here](http://depfind.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Ha! Thanks. Not sure how that's worked though, as I hit my daily points limit 10 minutes ago :-P

Answer (score 8):

[CDA - Class Dependency Analyzer](http://www.dependency-analyzer.org/) is incredibly simple to use, and can help you visualize those dependencies between packages and classes.

[image: CDA Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

I would also recommend Eclipse as there are various plugins for this task.
For example [ispace](http://ispace.stribor.de/) which can create a graphical representation of the package dependencies.

I general the [Source code analyzer](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/taxonomy/term/14,31) section of eclipse's market place has more plugins in that direction.

Answer (score 0):

You can test [JavaDepend](http://www.javadepend.com), it provides many useful features for dependency needs.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is Degraph: https://github.com/schauder/degraph (I'm the author, so this is obviously a shameless plug)