# Maven Dependencies for Java Packages

Tags: java, maven, dependencies

I have a Java project with a standard Maven hierarchy:

```
src
├── main
│   ├── java
│   │   └──com
│   │      └──foo
│   │         ├──bar
│   │         │  └──baz
│   │         └──qux
│   └── resources
└── test
```

How can I get a list of the dependencies used by the package `com.foo.bar.baz`?

Comment: `grep` the `import`s.

Comment: There might be some places where the full class name is used instead of `import`

Comment: By dependencies to you mean types (interface, class) or Maven `<dependency>`?

Comment: Maven dependencies

Comment: There are some static analysis tools that generate package dependency graphs, but I cannot find a recent thread, only older ones like https://stackoverflow.com/q/1392417/14955 https://stackoverflow.com/q/62276/14955 https://stackoverflow.com/q/19807372/14955 https://stackoverflow.com/q/53014342/14955

Comment: Any intelliJ or eclipse solution?

Comment: @Thilo, Thanks. I managed to use `jdeps` to find all dependencies of a package. I posted my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this done using [jdeps](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/jdeps.html). The usage is pretty simple:

```
jdeps <options> <classes...>
```

Where `<classes>` can be a pathname to a .class file, a directory, a JAR file,
or a fully-qualified class name.

**Some** of the options I found helpful in my case:

- `-verbose:class`: Print class-level dependencies excluding dependencies within the same package by default.
- `-classpath <path>`:Specify where to find class files.
- `-package <pkgname>`: Finds dependences matching the given package name (may be given multiple times)
- `-regex <regex>`: Finds dependences matching the given pattern
- `-filter <regex>`: Filter dependences matching the given pattern. If given multiple times, the last one will be used.
- `-filter:package`: Filter dependences within the same package (default)
- `-filter:archive`: Filter dependences within the same archive
- `-filter:none`: No `-filter:package` and `-filter:archive` filtering. Filtering specified via the -filter option still applies.
- `-include <regex>`: Restrict analysis to classes matching pattern. This option filters the list of classes to be analyzed.
- `-recursive`: Recursively traverse all dependencies.

**Sample Usage** for package `com.abc.xyz.ui`:

```
jdeps.exe -filter:archive -classpath <project_classpath> com\abc\xyz\ui\
```

Where `<project_classpath>` is the classpath of the project.

Output:

```
com.abc.xyz.ui (ui)
   -> com.itextpdf.text                                  itextpdf-5.5.12.jar
   -> org.apache.commons.io                              commons-io-2.6.jar
   -> org.apache.commons.lang3.time                      commons-lang3-3.8.1.jar
   -> org.apache.commons.text                            commons-text-1.6.jar
   -> org.controlsfx.control                             controlsfx-8.40.15.jar
   -> java.io
   -> java.lang
   -> java.net
   -> java.util
```

I used `-filter ^java\..*` option to exclude Java Runtime classes:

```
jdeps.exe -filter:archive -filter ^java\..* -classpath <project_classpath> com\abc\xyz\ui\
```

Output:

```
com.abc.xyz.ui (ui)
   -> com.itextpdf.text                                  itextpdf-5.5.12.jar
   -> org.apache.commons.io                              commons-io-2.6.jar
   -> org.apache.commons.lang3.time                      commons-lang3-3.8.1.jar
   -> org.apache.commons.text                            commons-text-1.6.jar
   -> org.controlsfx.control                             controlsfx-8.40.15.jar
```